# Separating concerns with React and D3 when using variable scales

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I've been following [Shirley Wu's post about using React with D3](https://medium.com/@sxywu/on-d3-react-and-a-little-bit-of-flux-88a226f328f3) and separating the concerns into separate files. The idea being that your modules in the `visualisation` folder handle the D3 attributes.

In my example, the file `visualisation/node.js` is responsible for setting the attributes for the circular nodes that represent the dataset. Their position should be based on their value property and a variable scale that has a domain set to the extent of the data values.

The scale itself is created in the parent component where the data is loaded and therefore I don't see any way of 'passing' this to `nodeViz.create` where the node attributes (including their position) are set. I also don't believe that that function / module have any awareness of the dataset to allow the scale to be re-created in the `node.js` file.

Is there a way to achieve this separation when using things such as scales to position elements? It feels like I must be missing something...

You can [see a version of this in codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/y24rvq15jv), but the code is also below:

**Chart.js**

```
import React from "react";

import { extent, scaleLinear, select } from "d3";
import nodeViz from "./visualisation/node";

const width = 800;
const height = 500;

class Chart extends React.Component {
  data = [
    { id: 0, value: 4 },
    { id: 1, value: 0 },
    { id: 2, value: 7 },
    { id: 3, value: 5 },
    { id: 4, value: 2 }
  ];

  xScale = scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain(extent(this.data.map(d => d.value)));

  createChart = () => {
    // The following would normally happen on componentDidUpdate
    // when we have some new data via the props, but in this
    // case we're not async so the data will already exist.
    const svg = select(this.node);

    const nodes = svg.selectAll("circle").data(this.data, d => d.id);

    nodes.enter().call(nodeViz.create);
    nodes.exit().remove();
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.createChart();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <svg ref={node => (this.node = node)} width={width} height={height}>
        <g />
      </svg>
    );
  }
}

export default Chart;
```

**visualisation/node.js**

```
const create = selection => {
  return selection
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3)
    .merge(selection)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("cx", d => d.value) // Should be xScale(d.value)
    .attr("cy", 150);
};

export default {
  create
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be honest, it's been so many years since I've written that article that I actually have some new opinions (though the core concepts remain the same).  In this case, the attribute setting is separated out for the purpose of being able to do things like transitions/animations with d3 (bc d3 needs to directly manipulate the DOM, so we don't want react to keep track of it).  What you have with the scales is in my mind a separation of data calculation and rendering, and in that case I do my data calculation all before the rendering phase.  So in that example, data calculation [happens in `_onChange`](https://github.com/sxywu/expenses/blob/73e6863ffa6c8ba4cd08e6cdd5203af6867f8c30/scripts/components/Graph.jsx#L70-L84) and rendering [happens in `render`](https://github.com/sxywu/expenses/blob/73e6863ffa6c8ba4cd08e6cdd5203af6867f8c30/scripts/components/Graph.jsx#L169-L190) and [`GraphVisualization.update`](https://github.com/sxywu/expenses/blob/73e6863ffa6c8ba4cd08e6cdd5203af6867f8c30/scripts/visualizations/Graph.js#L11-L15).

If I was to do it now, I'd probably just have React render everything (including the attributes) or have D3 render everything (so enter-update-exit everything).  I talk about that in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ladXdJ3KKd4).

Comment: Interesting to know that you'd actually do it in one or the other without mixing. Will have to go listen to that talk!